# Making a SQL database table browser using Entity Framework in c# winforms

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, performance, entity-framework

I'm just looking for some links or tips for some general direction. I'm writing a program where the user will have access to many different tables in a sql server database. For example, if a user clicks on the "Foo" button, it will bring up a gui dialog which displays all of the columns of the "Foo" table. It also has a textbox at the top for filtering through data in the columns. For the most part, what i've written so far works atleast decent, but there are times when the performance is really slow and I can't help but feel I'm doing something wrong. Generally my code goes like this.

```
//GUI Constructor will call a Load Function
private void Load()
{
    //Context is a DbContext entity
    var query = from q in context.Foo
        select q;

    datagrid.Datasource = query.ToList();
}
```

The part which I feel goes wrong is with the textbox filter searching. The way I do it right now is to basically re-query the database to get more specific rows. This function gets called on the TextBox TextChanged event. I know this would be bad to call every keypress, I was going to add a timer to wait for the user to stop typing before applying the filter but anyways this is the code though.

```
private void TextFilter()
{
    var query = from q in context.Foo.Where( x => x.Name == FilterTextbox.Text )
        select q;

    datagrid.Datasource = query.ToList();
}
```

I would assume it'd be better to store the entire database from the load function into a list that way all of the info is in the programs memory already, but this actually was slower than just querying the database again. I also tried using Context.Foo.Local and querying off of that but it proved to be as slow as storing all the data in my own List

```
private void AlternateLoad()
{
    context.Foo.Load();
    datagrid.Datasource = context.Foo.Local.ToList();
}

private void AlternateTextSearch()
{
    var query = from q in context.Foo.Local.Where( x => x.Name == FilterTextBox.Text )
        select q;

    datagrid.Datasource = query.ToList();
}
```

I've experimented with AsParallel() when using Local or my own List but it doesn't seem to make a difference. Anyways I just want to see how to speed this up. In one specific scenario, I was prefiltering the database before displaying the data, and the prefilter took about 19 seconds before it could display its 7 row result. The smaller tables are fine but the tables with 100k+ rows definitely reveal the weakness of the code. Any tips or just general links to on how to do this would be greatly appreciated. I've been searching all over and I have had no luck in finding anything.

Thanks very much!

Comment: For something like a database browser, I think EF is a bad fit. EF works best if you have a **defined, static model** of your database - but a database browser should be able to dynamically discover new tables, their columns and the data stored in them. I would recommend using just *raw* ADO.NET (`SqlConnection, SqlCommand`) for a database browser

Comment: Hmm, well I guess I dont mean it so much as an entire database browser but as a table browser/pick list. Just a way for the user to look at table records and edit them in another dedicated GUI if needed. @marc_s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really up to you to estimate what the best solution is for the application, but the following should be some solid pointers to continue:

Don't return data that you don't need:  top 100 rows / Paging

LINQ query ==> .First() .Skip() .Take()

In memory filtering can be very fast too! Keep the entire list in memory and run linq query against this collection...

Create StoredProcedures with a parameter to filter on and
put an index on the columns you must likely want to filter on.

Comment: Hmm paging, I totally forgot about that, I will have to look into that, I'll let you know how that comes out! Thanks!

Comment: So pretty much thinking about it, when you're dealing with 100k+ rows, no user is ever really going to search through that many. I decided to go with your idea of just displaying top 100 results. It works super fast now just using Take(100). Thank you very much sir!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding a private member variable to the class(a list):

```
public MyClass
{
  private List<Foo> myFoo = new List<Foo>();

  //GUI Constructor will call a Load Function
  private void Load()
  {
     //Context is a DbContext entity
     var query = from q in context.Foo
       select q;

    // set the private member variable "myFoo" here
    datagrid.Datasource = myFoo = query.ToList();
  }
  private void TextFilter()
  {
    // don't requery the DB, query the list myFoo
    //var query = from q in context.Foo.Where( x => x.Name == FilterTextbox.Text )
    //select q;

    var query = myFoo.Where(x => x.Column == SearchCriteria).ToList();
   datagrid.Datasource = query;
 }
}
```

Note: The above code isn't tested or anything, hopefully point you in the right direction.

Also Important:  Because you're not requering the database the data in the list could become out of date.

Comment: I've already tried keeping my own list to hold the data, for some reason it ran slower than querying the database. Not sure why. Thanks though!